# Underline Artifacts In amcharts.com Chart Title When Exporting As SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, amcharts

I want to underline the chart title when exporting amcharts.com charts but not during normal viewing of the chart.  Amcharts.com support suggested adding the underline as in inline style to the title at the time of exporting the charts.

You can find an example of the code here: https://codepen.io/bryanf/pen/jrNkwo.  I have modified the amcharts.com basic export example (here: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/exporting-chart-to-image/) to include the "onPrint" function suggested by amcharts.com support:

```
function onPrint (e, info) {
  var format = info.format,
      mimeType = info.mimeType,
      fileName = [info.fileName, info.extension].join("."),
      chart = this.setup.chart,
      chartExport = chart.AmExport,
      $div = $(chart.div);

  setTimeout(function () {
    $div.find(".amcharts-title").attr("text-decoration", "underline");

    chartExport.capture(info, function () {
      chartExport[["to", format].join("")](info, function (data) {     
        chartExport.download( data, mimeType, fileName );        
      });
    });
  }, 200);
}
```

The onPrint function is triggered for the various formats (PNG, JPG, and SVG) within the "menu" object (also used to set which menu options are present) of the "export" object:

```
"export": {
  "enabled": true,
  "menu": [{
    "class": "export-main",
    "menu": [ {
      "label": "Save Image",
      "menu": [ {
        "format": "PNG",          
        "click": onPrint
      }, {
        "format": "JPG",          
        "click": onPrint
      }, {
        "format": "SVG",
        "click": onPrint        
      }]      
    }]
  }]
}
```

This works for the PNG and JPG formats, but causes issues when exporting as SVG.  Specifically, the underline of the chart title extends for a ways beyond the end of the title and there is what appears to be a strikethrough around the midpoint of the title (e.g, through the letters "Cha" of "Chart" as shown in the Codepen example above).  Peculiarly, this appears when viewing the downloaded SVG file in Adobe Illustrator CS6 but not in Inkscape (both on Windows 10 desktop).  It seems to be browser independent (same results using Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and IE on Windows 10 desktop).

Amcharts.com support was unable to replicate the issue.  Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see it in Firefox, but Chrome and IE11 are fine for me (Win 7).

I think this might actually be a case where Firefox is doing the correct thing and other renderers may not be (see note at the end of this answer).

The part of the SVG that shows the title looks like this:

```
    <g transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 823 20) ">
    <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="22" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1" >
        <tspan x="-63.72" y="10.48" fill="rgba(0,0,0,1)">Test Chart</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

Note that there is whitespace before and after the `<tspan>` containing the title text.

However it is the parent `<text>` element that has the style `text-decoration="underline"`.

The reason this is important is because of what happens at the top of the file. The root `<svg>` element declares: `xml:space="preserve"`. By doing that, it is telling the renderer that all whitespace is significant and should be kept.  So the spaces before and after the `<tspan>` are supposed to be rendered - including their underline.

The reason you get the strikethrough effect is because the spaces before the tspan get underlined, and then the tspan changes the text position down and to the left before the rest of the title is displayed.

The fix is to either:

1. remove the whitespace before and after the `<tspan>`, or
2. change the `xml:space` attribute to `default`, which will cause the spaces to be suppressed.

**tl;dr**

There is a bug in the charting library's SVG exporter.  You should probably report it.

**Chrome**

The `xml:space` attribute is deprecated in the upcoming SVG2 specification.  That could be one reason why it is not affecting Chrome and/or some other browsers.  Chrome, in particular, has already started implementing some SVG2 features. However I don't know for sure whether removing `xml:space` is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Which application(s) did you use to view the saved SVG file?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, IE

Comment: We've released an update of the export plugin, which handles this issue. Thanks Paul for the whitespace hint :) https://github.com/amcharts/export/